# removing a CSS rule in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

You know how you can do `div.style.display = null`, and it will remove the inline css rule from the div, and the div will inherit its rule as if 'display' was never defined for it in the first place?

So it works on modern browsers, but not on IE. (At least not IE11).

How does one go about doing that on IE?

(Just to be more specific: I have a div that is being created with the rule of `display: none`, and I want to dynamically remove that rule and let that div act as if it was never defined with a display rule at all).

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you set a new display property?  You want other (unknown) CSS rules to apply to that div?

Comment: Exactly. I can't tell ahead what's the proper display value. ("block", "table"... etc)

Answer (score 1):

`div.style.removeProperty('display')` - works starting from IE 9 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975224(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the default value for the `display` property is "inline".

So, you can do this: `div.style.display = 'inline'`.

You can read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.